# Running Palm Desktop in Wine

Tags: macos, wine, palm-desktop

I'm using a Macbook Pro, and I'm trying to sync with a Palm Zire. After discovering that Palm Desktop for OS X is a PowerPC app, and won't run, I decided to install Palm Desktop for Windows inside of Wine (specifically Wineskin). After installing and starting, it crashes, saying that the configuration is invalid. I check the logs to find this:

```
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {fee984ea-751b-42f3-8219-6f611cb45621} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {fee984ea-751b-42f3-8219-6f611cb45621} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {fee984ea-751b-42f3-8219-6f611cb45621} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {fee984ea-751b-42f3-8219-6f611cb45621} could be created for context 0x7
```

So, obviously something is wrong with class {fee984ea-751b-42f3-8219-6f611cb45621}. Anyone know what that is?

Comment: A Palm Zire?  Still running?  Alright!

Comment: Probably not much help, but I still have my 2 Garrmin iQue 3600 devices [Palm OS 5, circa 2004] syncing nicely on Win 7 with Parallels, so that's always an option if you can't get Wine to play nice.

Comment: If a program crashes in Wine, you might want to file a bug report; if you do, the Wine team may fix the problem. Please read their [guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/Bugs) before doing so. ❧ The Wine team doesn't accept bug reports filed against Wineskin. You must use the latest development version (not the latest stable version) of Wine itself. ❧ If you do file a bug, please reply to me using the text "@unforgettableid:" and a comment with a link to the bug.

Comment: Are you running as the same user who installed Palm Desktop? If not see [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/1440425/133285) which fixes similar symptoms.

Comment: Since I posted this I switched to Linux and got rid of the Palm, so it's not really relevant anymore.