# Running Palm Desktop on Windows shows "Error: invalid configuration" and "Terminating the Palm Desktop"

Tags: windows, palm-desktop

When I run Palm Desktop as a user other than the one who installed the application it shows "Error: invalid configuration", "Terminating the Palm Desktop", then quits. Same result when running as Administrator.

One site I found says Palm Desktop must be installed separately by each user who intends to run it. This sounds redundant, plus I don't have the installer handy.

I'm running Windows 10 Pro 1809. I installed Palm Desktop before upgrading from Windows 8 (maybe Windows XP?).

Answer (score 0):

The article [Invalid Configuration - Terminating the Palm Desktop](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=350370) is a good start. LloydSev suggests

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\US Robotics\
>
> Export that ENTIRE key from the account which originally had Palm Desktop Installed on it.
>
> ...

To export, click on `US Robotics`, choose File>Export, make sure 'Export Range' is set to 'Selected Branch', then choose a file name, ex. Palm.reg.

Log into the new account and import the file created above, ex.

> regedit /s Palm.reg

I found this wasn't sufficient--I also needed to open `regedit` and replace all paths specific to the original user with ones for the new user, in particular

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\U.S. Robotics\Pilot Desktop\Core\Path

You may also need to update

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\U.S. Robotics\Pilot Desktop\MSI Properties\MASTERINIPATH

which I found pointing to a folder in `AppData\Local\Temp\`. (I didn't need to recreate that folder.)